# Regular Expression for Combined Look-ahead/Look-behind

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python and trying to write a regular expression that matches a hyphen (-) if it is not preceded by a period (.) and not followed by one character and a period.

This one is matching hyphen not preceded by a period and not followed by a character:

```
r'(?<!\.)(-(?![a-zA-Z]))'
```

Nothing I've tried seems to get me the right match for the negative look-ahead part (single character *and period*).

Any help appreciated. Even a totally different regex if I'm barking up the wrong tree altogether.

**Edit**

Thanks for the answers. I did actually try

```
r'(?<!\.)(-(?![a-zA-Z]\.))'
```

But I now realise that my logic was wrong, not my expression.

I've chosen the answer and upvoted the other correct ones :)

Comment: Can you give an example of ones that you tried and how they failed?

Comment: @BrenBarn Dunno about Python, but `(?<!\.)-(?!.\.)` should match a hyphen, if not precided by period and followed by one any character (which can be a period too) and a period. Is that what you mean? So this would match `a-.b` and `a-.b` but NOT `a-..` or `a-b.` or `.-`

Comment: `(?<!\.)-(?![a-zA-Z]{1}\.)` (note the `{}` specifying exactly one match to upper or lower case letters).

Comment: @SimonO101 ``{1}`` useless. ``[...]`` means : **one** character, whose value may be either **one** of the characters preent between the squared brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that by "character" you mean (and I base this assumption on your example and on @SimonO101's comment) `[A-Za-z]`, I think you are looking for something like this:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'(?<!\.)-(?![A-Za-z]\.)')
>>> r.search('k.-kj')
>>> r.search('k-l.')
>>> r.search('k-ll')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02D46758>
>>> r.search('k-.l')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02D46720>
>>> r.search('l-..')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02D46758>
```

There is no need to try to enclose the hyphen in a group that also captures the negative lookahead assertion. Trying to do this only complicates the matter.

Comment: Using `\w` will include 0-9?

Comment: @275365 Well in OPs sample one would assume, he means to match `[a-zA-Z]` *as chraracter* but *by one character* could be anything like `.` Nice answer btw.

Comment: Thanks, @Jonny 5. Also a good point. I removed the underscore, but you make an excellent point: . would be most in line with the word "character".

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

ss = '  a-bc1    d-e.2    .-gh3    .-N.4'
print 'The analysed string:\n',ss

print '\n(?!\.-[a-zA-Z]\.)'
print 'NOT (preceded by a dot AND followed by character-and-dot)'
r = re.compile('(?!\.-[a-zA-Z]\.).-...')
print r.findall(ss)

print '\n(?<!\.)-(?![a-zA-Z]\.)'
print 'NOT (preceded by a dot OR followed by character-and-dot)'
q = re.compile('.(?<!\.)-(?![a-zA-Z]\.)...')
print q.findall(ss)
```

result

```
The analysed string:
  a-bc1    d-e.2    .-gh3    .-N.4

(?!\.-[a-zA-Z]\.)
NOT (preceded by a dot AND followed by character-and-dot)
['a-bc1', 'd-e.2', '.-gh3']

(?<!\.)-(?![a-zA-Z]\.)
NOT (preceded by a dot OR followed by character-and-dot)
['a-bc1']
```

Which case do you want in fact ?